# Send Keys are not working on upload file element using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page to Automate which contains a file upload element (`<input type='file'/>`)

for uploading doc i am using **SendKeys(docUrl)**.

```
 this.WaitForElement("XPATH", xpathAppFileUploaderButton);
 fileUploader = this.FindControlByXPath(xpathAppFileUploaderButton);
 fileUploader.SendKeys(filePath);
```

the problem is, this code is running fine in IE8 but when i move to IE9(window7) &10(window8) upload button is not clicked.
i am using Selenium version 2.44.
Thanks in Advance.!!

Comment: Does that button works normally from site? in IE9 and IE10?

Comment: Yes,it is perfectly fine when i click manually in IE9 & 10 both.

Comment: Then it must work in other browsers. Do you getting any error?

Comment: No, i am not getting any error , i successfully get WebElement having property like: selected =false,displayed false,enabled=true,size and location etc.

Comment: I have noticed that in IE8,when i find upload element its displayed property is "true" but in IE9 & 10 it is "False"

Comment: What is exact properly? isenabled?

Comment: No Enabled property  is true in both IE, there is another property of IwebElement, "Displayed" when i debug my code in IE 8 Displayed is 'true' but in IE9 Displayed is 'false'

Comment: Then you will have to check by selenium code like  : driver.findElement(By.id("element")).isDisplayed() ? then perform action click. you will need to put this 1 condition.

Comment: but what i am thinking is ,why element is showing different property values in different browser

Comment: I think that is because each browser has its own way to load content..and many time we are facing issue with IE. after put that condition please let me know if it work or not.

Comment: i have added element.Displayed condition and then click on it but nothing happen,Each time its Displayed property showing 'false'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67461/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-adityak).